# df.groupby()[].transform('max') returns indices, not the data in the column

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel sheet with two columns of data. The data in the first column is grouped by rows the adjacent column contains some data to be processed. What I would like to do is take the data in column 'B' find it's maximum and print that max next to the data in column 'A'.

The data in both columns looks like

[image]

what I would like is

[image]

When I try

```
     df = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx", usecols= "A, B")
     df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('max')
```

The result is

[image]

Which returns the "max" but instead of the values in 'A' the indices are returned. Is there a way to do this with .groupgy, or do I need to try something else?

Comment: Can you add a copy-pastable form of the DF?

Comment: You need to assign your command: `df['out'] = df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('max')`

Comment: @mozway, thank you again! I am brand new to Pandas, do you have a tutorial or reference that you'd recommend?